# get parentNode of clicked element in plain JS

Tags: javascript, this, parent

I need to get the parentNode of a clicked element in plain JS (no jQuery or other frameworks)
I am currently using `document.getElementById("item_click")` 
but I want to change `id="item_click"` to `class="item_click"` so I can use multiple boxes.
I just don't know how to integrate `this` in the script

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/keDg2/) <<< play with it

HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <div  class="item-tester" >
        <div class="item-icon"></div>
        <div class="item-title">Item Title</div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_click" onmousedown="new_class(event)" onmouseup="revert_class(event)" onmouseout="revert_class(event)"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function new_class(event) {
    wClick = document.getElementById("item_click");
    wTile = wClick.parentNode;
    wTile.className = wTile.className + " added-class";
}
function revert_class(event) {
    wTile.className = "item";
}
​
```

I want to change

```
wClick = document.getElementById("item_click");
wTile = wClick.parentNode;
```

to something like

```
wClick = this;
wTile = wClick.parentNode;
```

I know how to do this in jQuery but it will not work in plain JS as `this`  would be the `window` (I think)

**BTW.
I need the (event) since this is just a stripdown of the entire code I'm using.**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
function new_class(event) {
    wTile = event.target.parentNode;
    wTile.className = wTile.className + " added-class";
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. not using 'this' ..but it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @pixelass: You should be aware that while it will work for your example, if you have and click on a nested element inside the `div` with the handler, it will stop working because `event.target` is always the most deeply nested element that received the event.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `event.target.parentNode` (*Don't need to even pass the `event` in the function*):

```
function new_class() {
    var parent = event.target.parentNode;
    // Do whatever...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> *"I just don't know how to integrate `this` in the script"*

Use `.call()` to invoke the handler to set its `this` value to the element that has the handler...

```
<div id="item_click" onmousedown="new_class.call(this,event)" ...>
```

---

```
function new_class(event) {
    var wTile = this.parentNode;
    wTile.className = wTile.className + " added-class";
}
```

Comment: I tried your example too. But in my specific case the other answer works perfectly. Like I said. the code is just a small part of the entire script and I ran into issues with your solution. Thanks for the Fiddle. I will try around and reconsider my checkmark if I get it to work in a better manner. +1 for the fiddle