# How to close the parent div on clicking the child element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have four div elements having same class but different Id. Inside each div i have one paragraph element and a span element. The span have same class but different id. Inside the span i use fa-times(close) icon to close the outer div. How to do it with JavaScript?

I tried declaring the variables using the class name but it returns an Array of HTML Collection. However, i am able to hide the parent div by targeting each element from inside the array. But I know this is the wrong method.

**CODE**

```js
function close() {
  var clost = document.getElementsByClassName('span');
  clost[0].parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="div_1">
  <p>Please Enter a Keyword</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="close()" id="span_1">
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_2">
  <p>Enter your name</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="close()" id="span_2">
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_3">
  <p>Enter your city</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="close()" id="span_3">
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_4">
  <p>Enter your country</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="close()" id="span_4">
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>
```

**Error**: Cannot find parent of Undefined

**Expected results**: All div should close separately on click on the fa-icon."

Comment: Is jQuery an option?

Comment: can use but want to use javascript.

Comment: _“Error: Cannot find parent of Undefined”_ – where do you get that error? The code you have shown, but into a jsfiddle, does not show any such error in Chrome.

Comment: You should not call your function `close` here - that has potential to collide with the `close` method of the window object. Choose a different name.

Comment: `clost[0]` would always be the first element with the class `span`, so that is not helpful. You could simply pass the current element into the event handler function as a parameter: `onclick="myclose(this)"`, `function myclose(element) { element.parentElement … }`

Comment: I retracted an earlier duplicate, but this is a dupe of [get parentNode of clicked element in plain JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9250634/215552).

Comment: the code used here takes one function to close one div. I cannot assign a separate function for each action. When i use clost.parentElement.style.display = 'none'; instead of last line. it returns like that.

Comment: Here's one way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3wLtav24/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `close` will not work as a function name, as you will get a conflict... so change it to something else like `closeDiv`.

The easiest way to do it with your current code and vanilla JS is to include `this` as a parameter in the `closeDiv()`, and then use that directly...

(Note, I have added the word `Text` to each `span` so you actually have something to click on)

```js
function closeDiv(spn) {
  spn.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="div_1">
  <p>Please Enter a Keyword</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="closeDiv(this)" id="span_1">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Text</i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_2">
  <p>Enter your name</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="closeDiv(this)" id="span_2">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Text</i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_3">
  <p>Enter your city</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="closeDiv(this)" id="span_3">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Text</i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_4">
  <p>Enter your country</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="closeDiv(this)" id="span_4">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Text</i></span>
</div>
```

---

If you have the option to use jQuery, it becomes a bit more simple...

```js
$(function(){
  $(".span").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" id="div_1">
  <p>Please Enter a Keyword</p>
  <span class="span" id="span_1">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Text</i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_2">
  <p>Enter your name</p>
  <span class="span" id="span_2">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Text</i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_3">
  <p>Enter your city</p>
  <span class="span" id="span_3">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Text</i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_4">
  <p>Enter your country</p>
  <span class="span"  id="span_4">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Text</i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: JS logic should not depend so tightly on HTML structure. Wrap that poor button into a decorative element and see your program fail miserably. Also for separation of concerns inline JS should be burninated.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass the id of the parent as argument to the close function?

```
<span class="span" onclick="close('div_1')" id="span_1">
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

And javascript:

```
function close (parentId) {
    var parent = document.getElementById(parentId);
    parent.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Simple and best answer. I'd just suggest not to use inline JS at all. We can do better than w3schools examples...

Answer (score 1):

```js
function closeDiv(event) {
  event.target.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
span{
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="div_1">
  <p>Please Enter a Keyword</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="closeDiv(event)" id="span_1">***
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_2">
  <p>Enter your name</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="closeDiv(event)" id="span_2">***
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_3">
  <p>Enter your city</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="closeDiv(event)" id="span_3">***
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_4">
  <p>Enter your country</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="closeDiv(event)" id="span_4">***
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

May I offer a simpler solution.

All your div's for close are the same, so you could use a delegated event.
Another advantage is if dynamic content is also added later, these events will work for new elements.

Some notes, you can attach delegated events at any point your DOM tree.  Here for a simple example I have just used `body`.  But if say you had another container that all your controls are in, you could attach there so that your delegated event doesn't fire when not required.

Also if your events need to stop bubbling down the DOM, you can use `evt.stopPropagation`, and you can even prevent the DOM default behaviour with `evt.preventDefault`.

Below is a simple example.

```js
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", 
 function (evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("fa-times")) {
    evt.target.closest("div").style.display = "none";
  }
 }
);
```

```css
.fa {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Please Enter a Keyword</p>
  <span>
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">❌</i></span>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Enter your name</p>
  <span>
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">❌</i></span>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Enter your city</p>
  <span>
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">❌</i></span>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Enter your country</p>
  <span>
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">❌</i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Minor issue - `closest` [doesn't work on IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Browser_compatibility) (although it does on Edge)

Comment: @freefaller  I personally always code for A grade browsers, and if I need support 
 for older browsers, it's polyfill's & transpiling.  MDN even have a polyfill for this too -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 0):

You should tell your close function which div to be closed by giving a parameter to the function. Then you can target this element:

Javascript

```
function close(divId) {
  var outerDiv = document.querySelector(`#{divId}`);
  outerDiv.style.display = 'none';
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="div" id="div_1">
  <p>Please Enter a Keyword</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="close(div_1)" id="span_1">
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_2">
  <p>Enter your name</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="close(div_2)" id="span_2">
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_3">
  <p>Enter your city</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="close(div_3)" id="span_3">
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="div" id="div_4">
  <p>Enter your country</p>
  <span class="span" onclick="close(div_4)" id="span_4">
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>
```