# Get node from event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the node from the event in order to append a new  on it.

```
const divToHighlight = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
divToHighlight.appendChild(<i className='icon' />)
```

I get the error `Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`
Is there a way to get the node from the event ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get parentNode of clicked element in plain JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250634/get-parentnode-of-clicked-element-in-plain-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are missing quotes around `<i className='icon' />`, it seems that you are trying to pass a `DOMString` to `.appendChild()` method but it won't work because [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method takes a `Node` as an argument and inserts it in the DOM.

You can use [`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) method which takes a `Node` or a `DOMString` as an argument.

```
divToHighlight.append("<i className='icon' />")
```

Alternatively, you could create `i` element using `document.createElement()` method and then insert it in the DOM using either `.appendChild()` or `.append()` method.

```
const elm = document.createElement('i');
i.classList.add('icon');
divToHighlight.appendChild(elm); // or divToHighlight.append(elm);
```

Comment: I did not understand how to use ParentNode.append() in my code

Answer (score 0):

You should create an `i` element first, before append it.

Try this:

```js
const i = document.createElement('i');
i.classList.add('icon');

const divToHighlight = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
divToHighlight.appendChild(i);
```